# How to use HostListener

Tags: angular

I am wondering how can I use `@HostListener`. The only info I've found, was in the [cheatsheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html) :

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(e) {...}
```

I am trying to log the element that user has clicked on. I've tried like that:

```
@HostListener('click')({
    onClick(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

But then I receive an error of:

```
TypeError: decorator is not a function(…)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The error message is quite accurate. A decorator is just for decorating a function (or a class, field, parameter, ...) Just put it before the code you want to decorate:

```ts
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue was also that I've placed it outside of the class. Any ideas on why 'e' may be undefined?

Comment: The alternative "outside" the class is to add it to the `@Component()` (or `@Directive()` decorator like `@Component({ ... , host: {'(click)':'onClick($event)'})` which does the same as the code in my answer. Actually no, if `onClick(e)` is called, `e` should have a value. Can you please try if `['$event.target']` makes any difference?

Comment: When I've added $event.target, it works as expected.

Comment: Interesting. What about the variant in the `@Component()` decorator with `$event` (without `.target`)?

Comment: It works as well, however it just provides different output. It then doesnt pass div I've cilcked on, it passes result of document.addEventListener

Comment: How does that differ from the expected result? Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: @Kuncevič I don't know. I never tried universal. Perhaps someone else ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, is it possible to use anonymous function instead of `onClick()`?

Comment: @Halfist no, any reason you want that?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I'd say there's no reason I want named function, since I don't call it by the name anywhere.

Comment: @Halfist then you have nothing to put the decorator on. Perhaps something like Option 1 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40652072/217408 (see also https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host)