# How to properly add document.addEventListener to Angular2?

Tags: angular

I've came across [cordova RemoteControl plugin](https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls) where, to listen to its event, the addEventListener is needed to be registered.

```
//listen for the event
document.addEventListener("remote-event", function(event) {
//do something
});
```

Is it a proper way for me to do it?

Comment: I think you can make use of `HostListener` like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349362/how-to-use-hostlistener

Comment: can you help to provide the answer pls?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 14):

Try the below step to add event listener using angular 2. I am not sure about "remote-event" event but "click" event is working fine for me as given below.

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) { 
   renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
     // Do something with 'event'
   });
}
```

## Update

As per comment below by @paqogomez.

`Renderer` has been renamed to `Renderer2` and `listenGlobal` to `listen`.

Comment: `Renderer` has been renamed to `Renderer2` and `listenGlobal` to `listen`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Event it's work for the dynamic innerHtml content :)

Comment: Do we need to manually "unlisten" to the event upon "ngOnDestroy"? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me like magic

```
 document.querySelector('#videostop').addEventListener('click', () => {
            //function here 
            console.log('your result');
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an EventListener to a constructor

```js
constructor() {
    document.addEventListener("remote-event", function(event) {
       //do something
    },false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @HostListener it's better solution
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-event-registration-document/
If u want to use document.someMethod for angular app also u can inject document in constructor:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener):

```
@HostListener('document:remote-event', ['$event'])
onDocumentRemoteEvent(ev: any) {
    // handle the event here
}
```