# How to Implement Metamask EventEmitter to Angular?

Tags: angular, ethereum, eventemitter, metamask

In Metamask Provider, there is an EventEmitter like this

```js
ethereum.on('accountsChange', (accounts) => console.log(accounts))
```

How to implement this to angular component? When I try to put this in component constructor like this

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentAccount: string;

  constructor() {
    ethereum.on('accountsChange', (accounts) => {
      console.log(accounts);
      this.currentAccount = accounts[0];
    })
  }
```

The console didn't log anything and `currentAccount` didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event to window object, and declare it before  component decorators.

```
declare var window: any;

// then
window.ethereum.on('accountsChange', (accounts) => {
      console.log(accounts);
      this.currentAccount = accounts[0];
})
```

Comment: Isn't window object already known by the component? why do we have to explicitly declare it?

Comment: Reference must be assigned for it to work properly in Angular

Answer (score 0):

After a long trip down the rabbit hole, here is how I solved our problem, hopefully it can work for you too (links & references are at the end):

At first, I tried using `window.etherem.on('accountsChange'...)` and never got it work properly in Angular 12. I was able to make it to work in javascript, but that was not an option in our case.

In my case I needed to listen for account changes made by the User in the Metamask Browser Extension and update the account in our web app. In the end I opted for an 'ethers' only approach, which worked and had the added benefit of saving space as our app currently uses their library.

### Metamask Component

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
...

export class Metamask Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
account: string;
selectedAccount = [];
ethereum: any;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
this.ethereum = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider((<any>window).ethereum, 'any'); }

 async ngOnInit() {
  this.connectAccount().catch(error => {
    console.error('Error in connectAccount', error); });

  this.listener();
 }

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.listener();
 }
}

async connectAccount() {
   this.selectedAccount = this.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts', [])
   .then((resolve: any) => {this.account = resolve[0]})
   .catch((error: any) => {console.error('Error', error)});
}

listener() {
  this.renderer.listen('window', 'focus', event => {
    this.selectedAccount = this.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts', []).then((resolve: any) => {
    this.account = resolve[0]
    }).catch((error: any) => {
    console.error('Error', error);
    });
  });
 }

}
```

### Metamask Template

`<div>{{this.account}}</div>`

### App Component Template

```
...
<app-metamask></app-metamask>
...
```

### Links & References I Used

[How to properly add document.addEventListener to Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255190/how-to-properly-add-document-addeventlistener-to-angular2)
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/other/#Web3Provider
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193#user-account-exposure-and-account-changes;

In our case I had to abandon the @metamask/providers approach because I could not get window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged...) to consistently recognize the change in Angular12. I hypothesize the problem has to do with how Angular change detection handles the host template, but I don't have a conclusive answer for that. Also, I had problems consistently accessing window.ethereum.selectedAccount, which updates each time the User selects a new account in the Metamask Extension, likely for the same reason. On a side note, I did have some issues getting it to work while in Chrome Dev Tools, but once I closed the tools and tested in a regular browser page the above worked as expected for me.

This is a somewhat simplified version that just listens for a change and updates the account string when one occurs.  It got me moving forward again, I hope it does the same for you.

Answer (score -1):

is easy just you need call "ChangeDetectorRef" and will detect the changes automatically

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(
    public cRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
  ethereum.on('accountsChange', (accounts) => {
    console.log(accounts);
    this.currentAccount = accounts[0];
    this.cRef.detectChanges();
  })
}
```

And done!

The above works for me, I hope that works for you too.