# How to bind click event to whole component (aka :host)?

Tags: angular

I have a container component `ContainerComponent` containing some children, `ChildComponent`, spawned with `*ngFor`.

`ContainerComponent` template:

```
<div class="child" *ngFor="let child of children">
    <child [child]="child"></child>
</div>
```

`ChildComponent` template:

```
<h2>{{child.name}}</h2>
<h2>{{child.data}}</h2>
```

For `ChildComponent`, I have a stylesheet defined, in which I can access whole component body using `:host` as described [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html).

With this, I created style for `ChildComponent`:

```
:host
{
    display: block;

    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Now, I want to bind the `(click)` event on each `ChildComponent` (whole component) and catch it inside `ChildComponent` class. To do this, I have to set `(click)="method"` property on *something*.

However, I don't have `:host`-like thing when talking about events.

I don't want to bind in `ContainerComponent`.

One possible solution is to wrap whole component in a `div` and bind event to this `div`, however I'm looking for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Option 1:

In component metadata specify click handler in host

```
host: {
   "(click)": "onClick($event)"
}
```

Implement the click handler in the component

```
onClick(e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Option 2:

Use HostListener to add listeners for the component.

```
import {Component, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

...
enter code here
...

@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: HostListener looks to be the preferred way for directive and component decorators (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03)